# codename one Mediaplayer slider

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I am trying to create a music playing app in codename one ,I am having problems when adding a slider to the media player.the slider is displayed when the app runs but it doesnt show the progress when the file is being played .this is the code i used to add custom play and pause buttons as well as the slider

```
     try {
     video = MediaManager.createMedia(sample_url, false);
     myslider.setMinValue(0);
     myslider.setMaxValue(video.getDuration()/1000);
     myslider.setIncrements(1);
     myslider.addDataChangedListener(new DataChangedListener(){
         @Override
         public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
            video.setTime(myslider.getProgress()*1000);

         }
     });


      } catch (Exception err) {
        Log.e(err);
        ToastBar.Status status = ToastBar.getInstance().createStatus();
           status.setMessage(" error loading sample file");
           status.show();
           status.clear();

    }
     sample.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,myslider);

    play.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
           //StreamFile(songDetails,sample_url);

          if(!video.isPlaying()){

          video.play();
           sample.removeComponent(play);
           sample.revalidate();
           sample.add(BorderLayout.WEST,pause);
           sample.revalidate();


          }

        }
    });
    pause.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            if(video.isPlaying()){
            video.pause();
            sample.removeComponent(pause);
            sample.revalidate();
           sample.add(BorderLayout.WEST,play);
           sample.revalidate();

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the code where you bind a listener to the media and set the value of the slider only the code where you bind a listener to the slider and set the value of the media. Notice you can use the native playback widgets see this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/media-controls-print-developer-guide.html

You need to periodically update the slider with the current play time of the media e.g. using a `UITimer` to update the current slider value. Make sure this doesn't trigger the event to fire and doesn't send you into a loop.

Comment: thanks for that response.Do you have any code samples I can use for binding the listeners and updating the slider

Comment: Not really but you can use something like `UITimer.timer(1000, true, () -> { sliderLock = true; slider.setProgress(media.getTime()); sliderLock = false;});`  Notice that in the event handling you'll have to check the lock variable to prevent cyclic behavior